# how connect with remote desktop connection to windows(not windows server)

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, rdp

how can I connect two pc with RDP on each pc I use windows(not server windows)

**error:**
remote desktop cant connect to the remote computer for one of this reasons:
1.remote access to the server is not enable
2.the remote computer is turned off
3.the remote computer is not availible on the network

and I want to know problem is on client or server pc
how resolve it

I want to know how resolve that error